# Map not autopanning when infowindow opens

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

According to the documentation a Google Map should auto pan when an info window opens so that the info window is entirely visible. This map is not moving. Any ideas why?

http://www.britishlegion.org.uk/support-us/local-projects

Comment: You are getting javascript errors, the most interesting of which is: `Error: google is not defined
Source File: http://www.britishlegion.org.uk/scripts/new/localprojects.googlemaps.smartinfowindow.js
Line: 30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in [localprojects.googlemaps.frontendlistener.js](http://www.britishlegion.org.uk/scripts/new/localprojects.googlemaps.frontendlistener.js) at line 72

The `mapObject`-argument passed to `MarkerLeftClickEvent`  is not a `google.maps.Map`-instance, it's an instance of your `googleMap`-"class", but the `open`-method of a `google.maps.InfoWindow` expects as first argument a `google.maps.Map`-instance.

Change this line in the `$.ajax`-callback:

```
infowindow.open(mapObject, marker);
```

into

```
infowindow.open(mapObject.map, marker);
```